# how to use correctly in the split command in tcl

Tags: list, split, tcl

I'm new to tcl and I tried to use in split command
my goal is to access to a path and delete the line number that are written in temp.txt

```
//this block was successful    
set f [open wave_test.txt]
set pid [open temp.txt "w+"] 
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {#spg_backref :\s+(.*)} $line all value]} {
        puts $pid $value
    }
}
close $f

//here I have a problem while printing the value of data that doesn't exist 
in the temp.txt file
set data [split $pid "\n"]
puts "the data is $data\n"
close $pid

//I think that there is a problem using " as a token in split command
foreach line $data {
    puts "set my list\n"
    set my_list [split $line ""]
    puts "my_list is $my_list\n"
    set path [lindex $my_list 1]
    set line_num [lindex $my_list 1]
    puts "the path is $path\n"
    puts "the line number is $line_num\n"
}


//I copied some lines from the temp.txt file
"/c/pages/smelamed/glass/var/tests/my_glass/rules/top.txt" 1145
"/c/pages/smelamed/glass/var/tests/my_glass/rules/target.txt" 114
"/c/pages/smelamed/glass/var/tests/my_glass/rules/other.txt" 3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `set data [split $pid "\n"]`, $pid is the *file handle* of the open "temp.txt" file, **not** the *contents* of the file

Since you opened the file w+, you can do

```
# write to the file
...
# jump to beginning of file and read it
seek $pid 0
set data [split [read -nonewline $pid] \n]
close $pid
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the required data, but I still have a problem with the split command.I think that I know what's the problem: when I use the command lindex I got only the first character in the string and not the whole string. I thought that when using the command split $line "" I will get a list like that {/c/pages/smelamed/glass/var/tests/my_glass/rules/top.txt} {1145} but I really don't have an idea how to set variables to the whole path and the number line. Do you know how can I do that after the split command?

Comment: @SapirMelamed you can use `set my_list [split $line " "]` or even `set my_list [split $line]` usually.

Comment: but the line number is not between the labels " " and I wanted to separate the values to two variables and I'm not sure that I can do it without splitting by the token "

Comment: @SapirMelamed: if `str` is `"/foo/bar" 99`, then `split $str` will give you the two-element list `{"/foo/bar"} 99`. In fact, if you are confident that the path never contains whitespace, you don't need to split the line: it is already in list form and you can use `lindex` directly on it.

Comment: wow!!! it works! so I had to write split $str instead of split $str ""??? Thank you! You are amazing!!!

Comment: No, the point is that you don't have to `[split]` each line in the first place. Just continue by accessing the value of `$str` as a list using `[lindex]`. `""` splits the string into its individual characters, `" "` as a separator char will explode the string not necessarily into a list as expected by your script, but into a list with empty-string elements. So, better avoid `[split]` here.

Comment: Hmm, somewhat disagree: one of the most common mistakes in Tcl programming is using lists like strings, and vice versa. I prefer to be explicit and convert strings to lists with `split` and the like.

Comment: Additionally, treating a string as a list actually breaks when you have unbalanced braces in the string. Try this: `set str "a string {with one open brace"; puts [lindex $str 2]` and then `set l [split $str]; puts [lindex $l 2]`

Comment: My comment is not meant as a general recommendation, rather applies to what we learn from the MVE along with the question and what Peter phrased as "you don't need to split the line", with all the necessary assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

`split $line ""` means splitting `$line` in a list of separate character. So if you have a string "abc", then `set mylist [split abc ""]` will give {a b c} and `lindex $mylist 1` equals 'b'. Simply write: `set path [lindex $line 0]`, because `lindex` automatically interprets `$line` as a list.

Using `split $line` may cause errors if the path name contains spaces.

You may also consider `lassign $line path line_num` to set both `path` and `line_num` in one command.

Comment: the tip to use lassign $line path line_num is very helpful, the path gets the correct value, but the variable line_num gets the whole line including the "path" and the line number, do you know why it happened? Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know what you did, but the following code should work as promised:`set pid [open temp.txt r];
set data [split [read -nonewline $pid] \n];
close $pid;
foreach line $data {
    lassign $line path lineno;
    puts $path;
    puts $lineno;
}`